# Check if polygon intersects with coordinates in a .csv file with PyQGIS standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, standalone

I have a bunch of .csv files with coordinates and a polygon. In my standalone script I would like to check if the polygon intersects with the coordinates.

So, when I write:

```
            for feature in polygon.getFeatures():
                if feature.geometry().intersects(file.geometry()):
```

It doesn't work because the coordinates in my 'file' are of type string and not a QGIS Rectangle.

I can use numpy to sort of get the extent of the coordinates as string by writing:

```
        data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=" ")
        x = data[:, 0]
        y = data[:, 1]

        xmin = min(x)
        xmax = max(x)
        ymin = min(y)
        ymax = max(y)
```

I feel like I have all the extents but now I need to find a way to check if they intersect. I'm stuck at this point. How can I do this?

I'm using QGIS 3.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a map layer from each CSV file ([read the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers)).

```
import glob

for file_path in glob.glob("/path/to/csv/folder/*.csv"):
    uri = "file://{}?delimiter=;&crs=epsg:3116&xField=x&yField=y".format(file_path)
    csv_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, file_path, 'delimitedtext')
```

Then (still inside that for) you can get each layer's extent and check the intersection.

```
for polygon_feature in polygon_layer.getFeatures():
    if polygon_feature.geometry().intersects(csv_layer.extent()):
        print("File '{}' intersects!".format(csv_layer.name()))
```

---

*Note: You seem to have a polygon layer and not just one polygon geometry. If that's the case you'll end up with nested `for` loops. Otherwise, if you have a single polygon geometry, you will just need a single `for` to iterate csv files.*

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try that. However, do we know anything about the time cost it takes to convert text to QgsVectorLayer objects? I was hoping to keep the text format to keep computation time as low as possible.

Comment: Well, you could also read each file, parse its coordinates (or perhaps just use the numpy method you mentioned), then make sure you create a proper extent (QgsRectangle) for your csv points, and finally check the intersection. In fact, you could also test the intersection against the BBOX of your polygon to make things a bit faster (that could be done even without a csv BBOX, just dealing with numbers). How to build a QgsRectangle is [described here](https://api.qgis.org/master/classQgsRectangle.html#a5fd6aa775689c2dc21193fe929cdd07b), if that's what you were looking for initially.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Your first suggestion works fine and I think its fast enough actually. I'll still check the QgsRectangle option though.